# Uso de condicional para lamentar sobre el pasado

Tags: gramática, condicional

En un artículo en inglés https://www.realfastspanish.com/grammar/the-spanish-conditional-tense-5-uses leí lo siguiente (en el punto 5):

> If you want to lament an action that happened in the past—this includes doing more or less of something—you can use the following structure:
>
> > ¡Por qué + condicional simple!
>
> Let’s look at a few actions:
>
> > Frustration: *Why didn’t I study more Spanish before arriving in Spain!*
> > Frustración: *¡Por qué no **estudiaría** más Español antes de llegar a España!*"

Preguntas:

1. ¿Lo que explica el autor es correcto? Pregunto porque nunca encontré esta estructura.
2. Por si no es correcto lo que explica el autor, ¿qué estructura se tiene que usar en estos casos? Yo sé solo del tercer condicional "si hubiera estado aquí habría dicho que..."

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La explicación y el ejemplo del autor del artículo:

> Frustration: Why didn’t I study more Spanish before arriving in Spain!
>
> Frustración: ¡Por qué no estudiaría más Español antes de llegar a España!"

son incorrectos.

En una situación como la descripta, se usaría -- sin necesidad de recurrir a una oración condicional -- el futuro perfecto del indicativo:

- ¡Por qué no **habré estudiado** más español antes de llegar a España!

Comment: Aquí hay una zona gris o una diferencia regional. A mi no me suena incorrecto aunque no lo usaría en caso de frustración sino en caso de duda y sobre todo refiriéndome a una tercera persona.  *¿Porqué X no estudiaría... ?*  En caso de frustración y en primera persona si usaría *¿Porqué no habré estudiado más...?*.  En Colombia es muy común, pero como ya lo hemos visto muchas veces que sea común no lo hace correcto. Realmente es incorrecto?